# Adding new app to itunes connect does not show up

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have the developer access to login to itunes. But when I login and click on My Apps the Add option does not show up. And it is not showing any agreements that has to be updated on main page.What is the reason?

Comment: Cross check twice. Cause if you have admin access then it should be shown

Comment: I checked logging out and again logged in. Still it is not showing

Comment: @MrugeshTank Sorry , I am having the role of a developer. Is this the reason?

Comment: Yes, You must be admin if you want to Create app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross check twice. Cause if you have admin access then it must be shown.
 As of now If you're admin then you can create app.

Comment: No , I have the role of developer. I have edited the question

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff , You must have admin role to create application. As of now, developers can not create application in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 0):

Only users with admin rights can have all the access of creating new app on app store.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [iTunes Connect user roles and permissions matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24), from the iTunes Connect Developer Guide. And [here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW1) how to set up iTunes Connect users, as well as TestFlight and sandbox beta testers, also from this guide.